# Converting a C++ class to a C struct (and beyond)

Tags: c++, c, class, struct

Past few days I have been "downgrading" > 1000 filem of C++ code into C. 
It's been going well until now. Suddenly I'm face to face with a class...

The compiler pointed out the error first in the header file:

```
class foobar {
    foo mutex;
public:
    foobar() {
        oneCreate(&mutex, NULL);
    }
    ~foobar() {
        oneDestroy(mutex);
        mutex = NULL;
    }
    void ObtainControl() {
        oneAcquire(mutex);
    }
    void ReleaseControl() {
        oneRelease(mutex);
    }
};
```

And of course, the C file has to take advantage of this

```
foobar fooey;
fooey.ObtainControl();
```

I don't even know where to start.... Help?

Comment: Isn't OO in C just `ObtainContol(&fooey);`? You an even call the parameter `this`.

Comment: @Bo But that isn't going to magically simulate RAII, which this class (and presumably others) is using.

Comment: @unapersson - Right, I focused on the second line of the code sample. The upside is that you don't have any exceptions either, so RAII is less important. "Just" add construct_foobar and destruct_foobar and call them at the right spots. Now remember why I like C++ better!

Comment: Why would you downgrade from C++ to C? What is the reason behind that decision?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turn foobar into a normal struct

```
struct foobar {
    goo mutex;
};
```

Create your own "constructor" and "destructor" as functions that you call on that struct

```
void InitFoobar(foobar* foo)
{
   oneCreate(&foo->mutex);
}

void FreeFoobar(foobar* foo)
{
   oneDestroy(foo->mutex);
}

struct foobar fooStruct;
InitFoobar(&fooStruct);
// ..
FreeFoobar(&fooStruct);
```

etc

Answer (score 5):

since C-structs can't have member functions, you can either make function pointers, or create non-member versions of those functions, ex:

```
struct foobar {
    foo mutex;
};

Construct_foobar(foobar* fooey) {
    oneCreate(&fooey->mutex, NULL);
}
Destroy_foobar(foobar* fooey) {
    oneDestroy(fooey->mutex);
    fooey->mutex = NULL;
}
void ObtainControl(foobar* fooey) {
    oneAcquire(fooey->mutex);
}
void ReleaseControl(foobar* fooey) {
    oneRelease(fooey->mutex);
}
```

and in the .C file:

```
foobar fooey;
construct_foobar( &fooey );
ObtainControl( &fooey );
```

Comment: You missed the final part: find every point at which `fooey` goes out of scope, and add calls to `destroy_foobar`.

Comment: yeah, that is true as well, you have to worry about automatic destruction on scoped variables

Answer (score 0):

There are actually compilers that compile from C++ to C. The output is not meant for human digestion, though, see [How to convert C++ Code to C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737257/code-convert-from-c-to-c).

Comment: thanks for the reference, problem is that the final code may very well need to be scrutinized (regulations...)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your compiler because there isn't a standard way of RAII in C. [See this question and the top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368385/implementing-raii-in-pure-c).