# How to transform C++ code into C in an elegant way

Tags: c++, c, header

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code convert from C++ to C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737257/code-convert-from-c-to-c)
>   [Converting a C++ class to a C struct (and beyond)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872915/converting-a-c-class-to-a-c-struct-and-beyond)

I used to be a C++ programmer, but now I need to write a program in C.
e.g. in C++

```
Main.cpp
=====================
int main
{
  ns::Sum sum(1, 2);
}

Sum.h
=====================
namespace ns
{
  class Sum
  {
    public:
    Sum(int a, int b);
    private:
    void AddThemUp();
    int a;
    int b;
  }
}

Sum.cpp
======================
namespace ns
{
  Sum::Sum(int a, int b)
  {
    this->a = a;
    this->b = b;
    AddThemUp();
  }

  void Sum::AddThemUp()
  {
     a + b;//stupid for returning nothing, just for instance
  }
}
```

That's in C++
I don't know how to put above in C. because there is no class there.
if I declare data member a & b in header file, they will become global variables.
I don't like global variables. and is there namespace in C?
who can help? thank you

Comment: C has structs and function pointers you can use.

Comment: All the functions in C is global? public to all?

Comment: @MPvaliantboy: Yup. Except if you declare them in a header and make them `static` (just like in C++).

Comment: Another discussion with many useful hints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737257/code-convert-from-c-to-c

Comment: The most elegant way is to post your code onto StackOverflow, ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple conversion from C++ to C. This method allows for stack objects, like how you use ns::Sum. As a note, you should also have a release function that cleans up any memory allocated by the structure.

```
// Main.c
// =====================

// Construction
ns_Sum sum;
ns_SumInitWithAAndB(&sum, 1, 2);

// Sum.h
// =====================

// All member variables are contained within a struct
typedef struct ns_Sum_
{
    int a;
    int b;
} ns_Sum;

// Public Methods
void ns_SumInitWithAAndB(ns_Sum *sum, int a, int b);

// Sum.c
// ======================

// Private Methods can be declared as static functions within the .c file
static void ns_SumAddThemUp(ns_Sum *sum);

void ns_SumInitWithAAndB(ns_Sum *sum, int a, int b)
{
    sum->a = a;
    sum->b = b;
    ns_SumAddThemUp(sum);
}

void ns_SumAddThemUp(ns_Sum *sum)
{
    a + b; //stupid for returning nothing, just for instance
}
```

Comment: You mean I can use a struct to store all the data members. And make it a parameter to some functions?

Comment: I dont know the meaning of keyword static here. not the same as C++?

Comment: @MPvaliantboy Yes, you can use structs to store data members. Static functions are only available to the current C source file, extern functions (the default) are made available to any C source file in the final linked binary.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is one of the limitations of C, you do not have separate `namespace`s built into the language. This is usually done by adding prefixes to names. As for global variables, you can use the `extern` storage specifier to declare but not define them.

Header:

```
#pragma once

extern int ns_foo;
```

Souce:

```
#include "header.h"

int ns_foo = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The conventional approach to use certain features which C++ gives you in C++ has to do with a lot of manual work:

- Instead of using namespace, you'd use prefixes for your `struct`s and functions, e.g., `struct ns_Sum` and `void ns_Sum_AddThemUp()`.
- C doesn't have member functions. So, instead of calling function on an object, you'd rather pass the object as a first parameter, e.g., `void ns_Sum_SumThemUp(ns_Sum* object)`.
- The way to make members `private` is to only declare the `struct` in the header and define it in the source. This goes together with suitable create and destroy function:

That is the declarations in a C header could look something like this:

```
typedef struct ns_Sum ns_Sum;
ns_Sum* ns_Sum_Create();
void    ns_Sum_Destroy(ns_Sum*);
void    ns_Sum_AddThemUp(ns_Sum const*);
```

For simple structures using a mapping like this works reasonable well. It becomes a Royal pain in the *some-body-part-goes-here* to also implement polymorphic dispatch or to deal with the moral equivalent of templates. My personal view of using C++ in C is to use C++ but I realize that this preference isn't shared with everybody...

Comment: `void ns_Sum_AddThemUp()` would be `void ns_Sum_AddThemUp(ns_Sum*)`, no?

Comment: @JensGustedt: yes, indeed. I corrected the example. Thanks!

Comment: And so now it has definitively your signature, with the `const` after the type :)

Answer (score 0):

Others already have pointed out how to use a name prefix to simulate a namespace.

But there seem to be another misunderstanding in your question. Only `static` data members translate to "global" variables in C. Other "normal" data members are distinct for each instance of your `struct`.

`public` `static` members *are* global variables, so you can not expect this to work better int C. `private` `static` members can be replaced by `static` variables that are only declared inside your `.c` file in which you define your functions. The only restriction is then that these are not visible for `inline` functions, as they would be for `inline` member functions in C++.

Another thing that should perhaps be added is that you could try to start to think in C when you are doing such a project. Modern C has some tools that don't exist in C++, the intersection of C and C++ is quite a restricted language. Such tools are, e.g:

- designated initializers that may replace constructors with an empty function body
- compound literals that provide temporary variables in expressions
- *pointers* to VLA (variable length arrays) that can provide you with convenient interfaces for vector and matrix functions